# Syntax for using echo inside an echo (wordpress slider)

Tags: php, wordpress, slider, echo

this is the piece of code I'm not sure how to deal with:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'smartslider2', true); ?>
<?php echo do_shortcode('[smartslider2 slider="InsertHere"]'); ?>
```

I simply want to insert the first echo instead of InsertHere. The first echo should output the content of a custom field. The second should recall the slider with the specific number inserted in the custom field. When trying different possibilities I only get errors.

Can anybody help?

Thank you :)

Comment: Supplement your question with error output

Answer (score 2):

Don't echo the first value, use it directly inside your second echo.

```
<?php 
 echo do_shortcode('[smartslider2 slider="'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'smartslider2', true).'"]');
?>
```

Or you can easily put that first value in a variable and use that variable in the second line

```
<?php $slider = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'smartslider2', true); ?>
<?php echo do_shortcode('[smartslider2 slider="'.$slider.'"]'); ?>
```